# Matching all characters in a set

Tags: regex

I want to be able to match `!=` when both `!` and `=` appear together.

I have the following RegEx pattern so far: `(\'.*\')\s*([!=]|\bNOTLIKE\b|=|\bLIKE\b|\bIN\b)\s*(.*)`

The following examples should demonstrate how the pattern behaves:

`'DocID' = 1234` = Valid

`'DocID' NOTLIKE 1234` = Valid

`'DocID' != 1234` = Valid

`'DocID' IN 1234` = Valid

`'DocID' ! 1234` = Invalid

In its current state, `!` can be entered by itself and be valid (incorrect). How can I modify my RegEx to include `!=` as a valid input in the 2nd capture group?

Comment: You mean `!?=`?

Comment: yup, `(\'.*\')\s*(!?=|\bNOTLIKE\b|\bLIKE\b|\bIN\b)\s*(.*)` should do

Comment: `/\s(!?=|(NOT)?LIKE|IN)\s/`?

Comment: `(\'.*\')\s*(\!\=|\bNOTLIKE\b|=|\bLIKE\b|\bIN\b)\s*(.*)` ?

Comment: Replace `[!=]` with `!=`, the character class means you match a single char from the set. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/naahcq/1/).